# NameError uninitialized constant Model::Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, nameerror, uninitialized-constant

I'm new to ruby on rails. Ihe error I have is

```
NameError in ReviewsController#create
uninitialized constant User::Review
Extracted source:
    @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
```

I read on other stack overflow questions that usually the error for wrong names or forgetting belongs_to or has_many but I believe I've set the relations correctly. I am using the gem devise to handle the user and sign in/sign up etc

**Reviews.rb**

```
class Reviews < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :renters

end
```

**User.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :reviews
end
```

**Reviews_Controller.rb**

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_renter
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @review = Reviews.new(renters: @renter)
  end

  def create
    @review = current_user.reviews.build(review_params)
    @review.renter = @renter
    @review.save 
    redirect_to @renter 
  end

  private
    def set_renter
      @renter = Renters.find(params[:renter_id])
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:reviews).permit(:comment, :rating)
    end
end
```

The Renters model is working fine and similar code I have to make a new Renter is working so I am not sure what is wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ActiveRecord::Base` classes are usually named in singular.

Ruby on Rails naming conventions expect your class to be named `Review` and it should be stored in a file named `models/review.rb` (but still store its entries in a `reviews` database table).

If you do not want to follow this convention, then you have to explicitly tell Rails that the class is named differently in the definition of the `belongs_to` and `has_many` association.

Because such conventions make it much easier to work with Ruby on Rails, I highly recommend following and not fighting those naming conventions.

Comment: thanks, didn't know the classes had to be singular. changed my models and controllers as well as paths and its now working thanks

Answer (score 0):

your model class for your `reviews` table should be `Review` in the file: **app/models/review.rb**

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :renters
end
```

and your `User` model representing `users` table should be in the file:  **app/models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :reviews
end
```

NOTE: for this association to work, your reviews table must have a column `user_id` as the foreign key for performing activerecord operations on associated models (for example: `User.find(1).reviews` to get all records of `reviews` table whose `user_id` is 1)

Answer (score 0):

This occours by convention of Rails. You can force with function `class_name` the class `Reviews`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :reviews, class_name: "Reviews"
end
```